# How can I find duplicately named files in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, duplicates, filenames

I am organizing a large Windows folder with many subfolders (with sub folders, etc...), in which files have been saved multiple times in different locations.  Can anyone figure out how to identify all files with duplicate names across multiple directories?  Some ways I am thinking about include:

- A command or series of that could be run in the command line (cmd).  Perhaps DIR could be a start...
- Possibly a tool that comes with Windows
- Possibly a way to specify in search to find duplicate filenames
- NOT a separate downloadable tool (those could carry unwanted security risks).

I would like to be able to know the directory paths and filename to the duplicate file(s).

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.  I recommend trying this on the SuperUser site.

Comment: There are shareware and perhaps also freeware Windows GUI applications for this task, for example [UltraFinder](https://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultrafinder/), [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), ... So there is absolutely no need to reinvent the wheel by coding a batch file solution for this task. Those applications are even more powerful as they can find also duplicate files with different file names in various directories, but identical file data. Those tools are as secure as Windows itself. Microsoft Excel is also not installed with Windows, at least not activated (licensed).

Answer (score 0):

Not yet a full solution, but I think I am on the right track, further comments would be appreciated:

From CMD (start, type cmd):

```
DIR "C:\mypath" /S > filemap.txt
```

This should generate a recursive list of files within the directories.

TODO: Find a way to have filenames on the left side of the list

From outside cmd:

- Open filemap.txt
- Copy and paste the results into Excel

From Excel:

- Sort the data
- Add in the next column logic to compare to see if the current text = previous text (for filename)
- Filter on that row to identify all duplicates

To see where the duplicates are located:

- Search filemap.txt for the duplicate filenames identified above and note their directory location.

Note: I plan to update this as I get further along, or if a better solution is found.

Comment: Hint: Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` for help on this command. You can read about `for /R` (recursive search for file names) and `%~nxI` (just name and extension), `%~fI` (full qualified name = drive + path + name + eXtension). Correct used with `echo` redirected into a file on __for__ command line and this list file sorted with `sort` according to help output with `sort /?` might be useful for your reinventing wheel coding task. A second `for` loop could be used to find the duplicates and remove the others from list. But file size `%~zI` should be additionally evaluated.

Comment: @Mofi That looks promising, and potentially a better solution, thank you!